# R and lubridate: create intervals in a time series using a criteria

Tags: r

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around creating a series of intervals from some time series data.

If I have a data frame (df) with date, concentration, and whether that concentration exceeded a threshold of 5:

```
df <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(1356183950, 1356184851, 1356185750, 
1356186650, 1356187551, 1356188450, 1356189350, 1356190250, 1356191150, 
1356192050, 1356192950, 1356193851, 1356194750, 1356195650, 1356196550, 
1356197450), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    CONC = c(3.8, 3.8, 3.7, 4.3, 5, 6, 7.2, 7, 6, 5, 4.3, 
    3.7, 3.4, 3.3, 3.1, 3), EXCEED = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("DATE", "TURBIDITY", 
"EXCEED"), row.names = 1070:1085, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create an interval for each time period based on consecutive measurements below or above the threshold and return summary statistics , something like:

```
   START                END                 MAXCONC
1  2012-12-22 13:45:50  2012-12-22 14:30:50 4.3
2  2012-12-22 14:45:51  2012-12-22 16:00:50 7.2 
3  2012-12-22 16:15:50  2012-12-22 17:30:50 4.3
```

I can't figure out how to create the distinct intervals using lubridate. Is there another package I should be using? Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick possible `data.table` solution. I've used `rleid` function from the [development version on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) but you could just use the base R `rle` function instead

```
library(data.table) # v>=1.9.5
setDT(df)[, .(
              START = min(DATE),   
              END = max(DATE),
              MAXCONC = max(TURBIDITY)
              ),
          by = rleid(EXCEED)]

##    rleid               START                 END MAXCONC
## 1:     1 2012-12-22 13:45:50 2012-12-22 14:30:50     4.3
## 2:     2 2012-12-22 14:45:51 2012-12-22 16:00:50     7.2
## 3:     3 2012-12-22 16:15:50 2012-12-22 17:30:50     4.3
```

Comment: Thanks! I should be able to calculate the additional statistics I need using the START and END dates in lubridate. I also learned a new term that will be immensely helpful, "run-length encoding"... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just adding the implementation I settled on (i.e., by using `data.table::rleid` and `dplyr` for an alternative solution.

```
    library(data.table) # v >= 1.9.5
    library(dplyr)

    df %>%
      group_by(RUN = data.table::rleid(EXCEED)) %>%
      summarize(START = min(DATE),
                END = max(DATE),
                MAX = max(TURBIDITY)) %>%
      mutate(DURATION_HRS = as.numeric((END - START)/60))

#  RUN               START                 END MAX DURATION_HRS
#   1 2012-12-22 13:45:50 2012-12-22 14:30:50 4.3      0.75000
#   2 2012-12-22 14:45:51 2012-12-22 16:00:50 7.2      1.24972
#   3 2012-12-22 16:15:50 2012-12-22 17:30:50 4.3      1.25000
```

Comment: What's `as.duration` and `interval`?

Comment: `lubridate::new_interval` creates an interval object with the specified start and end dates and `lubridate::as.duration` coerces that object to a duration object in seconds.

Comment: You don't need this, just do `mutate(DURATION_HRS = (END - START)/60)`. Every time I look on the functions in `lubridate` it seems like everything is over complicated there...

Comment: Good call! Thanks. I cleaned up the code to reflect your suggestion.